# Using Google app script, hangout image aspect ratio not working

Tags: google-apps-script, chatbot, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

Even if we assign any numbers in **aspect ratio** (Width/Height), displaying the default image size in the hangout chat

```
"cards": [
  {
    "sections": [
      {
        "widgets": [
          {
            "image": {
              "imageUrl": "https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/black-gmail-icon--2.png",
              "aspectRatio": 10
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
]
```

please verify the issue in screenshot -

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of the output?

Comment: Yes, @ZektorH now you can find the screenshot from the link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZvK6.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not working as of now.

I have filled an Issue for you [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143860570/).